# Binary raster shows NAs

Tags: r, raster

I have reclassified a raster using a 5% threshold. When I checked the raster for the total number pixels with values 0 and 1, using the "freq" function, it showed NA values.

```
#Binarization

M5 <- c(0, 0.2026350, 0, 0.2026350, 1, 1)

RM5 <- matrix(M5, ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE)

binary_global_5 <- reclassify(global,RM5)

# Frequency of cells

freq(binary_global_5)

      value   count
[1,]     0  961602
[2,]     1 1251653
[3,]    NA 5152345
```

Actually, the NAs are 1s. May I know where I am doing wrong

Rahul

Comment: is `M5` the M in `RMS <- matrix(M, ncol =3`, or another object that isn't otherwise used here?

Comment: it was actually M5. I corrected it now in the question.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the range for reclassification is closed on the right. You need to flag that both extreme values need to be included in the reclassification:

```
binary_global_5 <- reclassify(global, RM5, right = NA)
```